# My wordpress blog is getting more views and visitors but my website does not while it has same data over it

Tags: wordpress

I have created a wordpress blog previously and it is working very fine and getting lot of visitors and users but when I have created/hosted my website using same wordpress blog but it is not getting that much visitors and views.How it is happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be because you are not continuously upgrading your website so that it can be easily searchable in google's or search engine's searching. Wordpress blogs are continuously getting upgraded using keywords to get the ranking in search engines. In simple words, you should focus on your website's SEO (Search engine optimizer) so that it can perform better.

Comment: Ya I think this can be the reason for low ranking. Thanks :)